# React D3 - Uncaught TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data(...).join(...).attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I am trying to generate a simple svg using d3 in react that will show 2 circles of different sizes corresponding to the minimum and maximum values of the `sValueArray` prop passed to the component, hence `data` looks something like `[2, 40]` and is logged to the console correctly. My code is as follows...

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { select } from 'd3';

function D3SizeBar(props) {
    const svgRef = useRef();

    const data = [0, 0]
    data.splice(0, 1, Math.max.apply(Math, props.sValueArray))
    data.splice(1, 1, Math.min.apply(Math, props.sValueArray))
    console.log(data)

    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = select(svgRef.current);
        svg
            .selectAll('circle')
            .data(data)
            .join('circle')
            .attr('r', value => value);
    }, [props.sValueArray]);

    return (
        <svg ref={svgRef}>
        </svg>
    )
}

export default D3SizeBar;
```

However I am getting an uncaught type error

> Uncaught TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data(...).join(...).attr is not a function

and an Uncaught (in promise) type error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data(...).join(...).attr is not a function

Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong, this is the first time I have used d3 so it is all very new. I have got the code so far mainly from this YouTube tutorial video by The Muratorium -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-ThTzB-Zjk

Comment: ``console.log`` the path from the error; strip away functions from right to left and see what you are working with. Prepend a ``typeof`` in the console statement to see your types match.

Comment: Try import * as d3 from 'd3'; then  const svg = d3.select(); and check which version of D3 you use (should be 4.x or later)

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Thanks, this has worked, I think something was wrong with my d3 install